# ruby hash storing

Tags: ruby

I want to take the current time and store it in hash and then when I check it again compare the current time to the stored time.

```
t1 =Time.now
time = "#{t1.hour}" + "#{t1.min}" + "#{t1.sec}"
oldtime = Hash.new(time)
puts "Old time is #{oldtime}"
puts "Current is #{time}"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Implementation aside, what are you trying to do?

Comment: If the times changes, store time vs new time, then I will launch a new program

Comment: I have coded in other programs where you could store a value in a hash and reuse it as needed. Just don't know how to do it in Ruby.

Comment: @ragragruby can you give example what type of output you are expecting in your hash?

Comment: So why do you have to put that in a hash again?

Comment: what super cow power do you give to an hash ? It's just a key/value mapping. There is no persistent storage associated with it. If you want to store something just put it in a plain variable. I suggest you give use some code sample of what you are trying to do in a language you know. Then we may figure out what you want to do with ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Your `t1` and `time` variables will not change. `Time.now` gives you a **snapshot** of what the current time is, but as time advances, previous variables which were assigned the value of `Time.now` will still have the same value as when they were set. Putting the time value inside a Hash will make no difference, whatsoever.

If you want to check the time later, you will have to get `Time.now` again.

```
t1 = Time.now
# ... time passes
t2 = Time.now

# Now you can compare t2 to t1 to see how much time elapsed.
```

Comment: I guess time was a poor choice on my part. What I'm trying to do is, I parse out the time stamp of a file in my file system. I keep checking till it changes and when it does I call a different program. Not sure how to keep the original value on the next check for comparison purposes

Comment: is it a stand alone program or is it on rails ?

Answer (score 0):

Why convert to a string?  You are introducing errors, as the time 10:05:02 will convert to "1052" with your code.

Instead, store the time object directly:

```
timestamps = {}
timestamps['old'] = Time.now
... more code ...
timestamps['new'] = Time.now

puts "Old time is: " + timestamps['old'].to_s
puts "New time is: " + timestamps['new'].to_s
```

If you want to compare the timestamps, you can use the spaceship operator like:

```
timestamps['old'] <=> timestamps['new']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
last_filetime = nil
while true
  filetime = file.timestamp
  call_other_process if last_filetime and filetime != last_filetime
  last_filetime = filetime
  pause 10
end
```

Does this help?